# Does reactJS has filters as we have in angularJS.

Tags: reactjs

Does reactJS component has filters as we have in angularJS.

For example: 
AngularJS

`<img src={{url | uppendExtension}} />`

I want something like this:
ReactJS

`<ImgComponent src={url | uppendExtension} />`

Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a function call. There is no special syntax for this in React (nor is there a need for such).

```
<ImgComponent src={uppendExtension(url)} />
```

Comment: `just do a function call` this can also be done in angularJS. But angularJS have given support for filters out of the box. 
How are you going to handle multiple filters?

Comment: Just pass the result of one function call as an argument to the next: `foo(bar(baz))`.